# Passing data between python and javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, web.py

I'm creating a web form.  Depending on the value of the first field I want to show different fields in the rest of the form.  I can use javascript to update the form:

```
document.getElementById("formdata").innerHTML = HTML_string
```

I'm using web.py.  The list of fields I need is stored in MongoDB and I'm using python to pull out the list.  Looks like I should be using JSON to pass the data from python to the browser.  There are lots of simple examples serving only JSON (like https://gist.github.com/sirleech/5055971) and the following almost exactly describes what I need: [Passing variables between Python and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689695/passing-variables-between-python-and-javascript).  How can I use that data with JavaScript while still rendering a full HTML page?  Has anyone got any examples I can use to make a functioning web page?  And is it possible to call the python script when the field value is changed and pass the query reslts back to the browser without refreshing the page?

I'm not sure if what I am trying is the best way of doing this so I'm open to other suggestions.

Thanks,

Ger

Comment: Sounds like maybe your question is how to unpack/use JSON data on the browser side? Typically, this is done by some kind of AJAX request/callback in JavaScript. If you are doing this for the first time, I'd suggest looking into AngularJS or jQuery as tools for abstracting away a lot of browser-specific headaches.

Comment: Yes, I think that is my question!  Thanks for the tip, I'll try and find a tutorial on these now I know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, JSON is used to supply data, not markup. You typically already have HTML loaded and insert JSON data into DOM elements immediately after it is acquired.

Let's say you want to update a "score" element that's marked up like this:

```
<p>My Score: <span id='my_score'></span></p>
```

To do this, let's say your JSON "score" feed is hosted at /data/score. It returns JSON like this:

```
{score: 5}
```

If you were using jQuery, for example, you could request and update this value as follows:

```
$.get('/data/score', function(data){
    $('#my_score').html(data['score']);
});
```

But that makes a lot of assumptions about what you're using and how it works.

Comment: Ok looks like this isn't going to be a quick fix.  I best get learning jQuery!

Comment: @Geraint Yeah, the asynch request use pattern takes a bit of learning, too. You have to learn to think in events and callbacks instead of assuming that everything happens in a specific order. This stuff gets complicated quickly and if you're really just starting here, it might be worth the effort to learn a framework like Angular. http://angular.codeschool.com/