# how to use Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i need to get some value from my html file but i have a few questions that aren't answered in the [Beautiful soup quick start tutorial](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). What i want to do is to extract a number that was given by the user on my website and then use this number in a sql query so i might not need beautifulsoup in order to do that but i don't know any other way to do it. 1/ Do i need to execute my html file in order to extract the value ? 2/ Do i need to put all my html code in the `html` var ? because in the quick start he puts everything in it put it looks very inaproriate for big html files. here's my code so far :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<input type="number" id="numbers" name="numbers" min="10" max="100">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('input')['name'], ':', soup.find('input')['value'])
```

my website is written in html / css (it's still running in local) and looks like this[image: my website]

i'm trying to extract numbers from the "number of rows" field

Comment: No, this is exactly the opposite of what BeautifulSoup is for.  BS4 is when you are pretending to BE the user.  You said "on my website".  What is your website written in?  What framework?

Comment: Are you aware how HTML forms work?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm a total beginner so i'd say no

Comment: Then, HTML including forms (and how they are transmitted) should be one of the things to learn first.

Comment: ok i'll look at that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get the value from the input, a simple js or PHP will do the trick.

Javascript:

```
<input type="number" id = "numbers" min="10" max = "100">
<input type="button" onclick="getNumber()" value ='click me'>
<script>
    function getNumber(){
    var number = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
    console.log (number);}
</script>
```

Comment: and then i can use `var number` in my python script ?

Comment: You will have to pass the variable to python. This post might help you understand how to do so: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689695/passing-variables-between-python-and-javascript)